# select only one object via jQuery and submit it with a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am building a small quiz app and the choices are all list items (li)

In jQuery or javascript how would I be able to allow the user to select one answer (it is ok if I need to add an 'a' tag) and then when they click submit (which can be done via javascript or jquery) the value is submitted with it. Also when the user clicks an option; where would I put the jquery code to manipulate the css.

Sample Code:

```
<li id="q1" value="1">Option 1</li>
<li id="q2" value="2">Option 2</li>
<li id="q3" value="3">Option 3</li>
```

Thanks in advance. If I sound a bit confusing or you can't figure out what I'm trying to say please comment and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Are you looking for markup to be able to use a `RadioButton`? Like on this sample? http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_RADIO.html

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange that's a good way to put it yeah.... I want the same functionality of a radio button but I also want to beautify the interface a bit.

Comment: @4cpukid You can use CSS to control how the `radiobutton` looks like. It is exactly the same as `<div>` and `<li>`.

Comment: @Derek yes I have that right now however when the user clicks on an option the CSS will change (for example add a blue background) and if another answer is selected disable the previous one back to its' original state and activate the new option. My biggest issue is trying to figure how to make the list items act as radio buttons and how to pass the values on via a standard form submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use (or at least try) a

```
<input type="radio">
```

to avoid all those ugly JavaScript mess.

### Method 1

```
<label><input type="radio" name="Question" value="1">Option 1</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="Question" value="2">Option 2</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="Question" value="3">Option 3</label>
```

Use:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
```

To clear out **all** style from default `<input>` so that you can apply background, color, borders, or whatever you like there.

### Method 2

```
<li><label><input type="radio" name="Question" value="1">Option 1</label></li>
<li><label><input type="radio" name="Question" value="2">Option 2</label></li>
<li><label><input type="radio" name="Question" value="3">Option 3</label></li>

input[type=radio]{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
}
```

Using this method, the radio button will also be selected when you click on the `<li>`. Plus you can style your `<li>` too!

**LIVE DEMO:** [***http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CDV7q/***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CDV7q/) (with some additional modifications)

Comment: Just to confirm before I try anything... both methods would remove the unwanted selection bubble?

Comment: What do you mean, `unwanted selection bubble`?

Comment: I want this to be a multiple choice selection (like a classic game show) however most radio button inputs have the circle that can be selected. I do not wish to have the bubble part... I just want the functionality of a radio button without the radio button part.

Comment: YES! thank you super much! When I get enough rep I'll make sure to come back and thumb your answer up :)

Comment: Can I bug you for just one last question please :)... I copied the code from the fiddle and its great however my buttons are laid out like this: <li><label><input><span>TEXT</span></label></li>. When the option is selected I want the CSS on the li to change and in the CSS I noticed that you have +span which obviously changes everything in the span tag INSIDE the label. I tried replacing the +span with +li but no luck. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't change the CSS of `<li>`, change the CSS of the `<span`>s.